# How to show the company name and banner in the App Search results

Tags: ios-appstore

As shown in the image below, the names of some companies are displayed in the App Store result results with a large banner image. How can I show my company's name and image in results. There is no any section to upload an image or set this kind of information in the iTunes Connect.

[image]